# Convert pandas dataframe to html table

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

I am working on a django application. In the application I am trying to display a pandas dataframe in a django template. I am loading a csv file as follows.

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, str(request.FILES['file'])))
table_content = df.to_html()
context = {'table_content': table_content}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to display the table. In the template I am retrieving the dataframe as `{{table_content}}`. But this just displays the html code for the table and not the table itself. I can do a HttpResponse to display the table, but then the rest of the content in the template disappears and only the table is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use autoescape (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ table_content }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: This will work. You can also use `{{ table_content|safe }}`